# Reputation graph popup overflows its container

Tags: bug, reputation-history, reputation-graph

The popup on the [reputation graph](//stackoverflow.com/users/2773837/hatchet?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2016-02-27%2014:21:16Z) overflows its container:

[image: Reputation graph popup overflowing. Freehand circles!]

The content of the popup is in *two* places: an element inside the `<svg>` of the graph: `g.highcharts-tooltip` (but the text inside has `visibility: hidden`), and an element immediately after the `<svg>`: a `<span>` which is visible, and appears to be overflowing.

The second element is the source of the problem.

---

I'm on Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (Fedora 23), reproduced on FireFox 44.0.2, Vivaldi 1.0.344.37.

Comment: Typically, you post the "Solution" in the answer box, leaving only the "Problem" in the question.

Comment: Yup - or change it to [Solved].

Comment: @CodyGray It's not solved, though. If it was, the problem wouldn't be there any more. You're right, though. I'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: I hope @rad was kidding. [Solved] never belongs in a question's title or anywhere else. A proposed/potential solution is perfectly acceptable as an answer to a bug report, however.

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove the `<span>` below the `<svg>` completely, as it is both redundant and overflows the popup box.
2. Remove `visibility: hidden` from the text inside the `<svg>` of the graph.

[image: How to fix]

Result:

[image: Fixed result]

The popup is now properly displayed.

---

Whoever would be able to fix this, please do! :)